# Express engine (e.g. EJS) and REST together

Tags: jquery, json, node.js, rest, ejs

I am building a web app which would allow me to keep track of my sport sessions and in the process I am learning about nodejs, mongoose, mongodb and EJS.

Here is my declaration to use EJS:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
```

I have developed a number of pages with the EJS engine, but I have a page with lots of data and I am looking for a solution where I can render the main data through EJS and retrieve the additional data to display through jQuery and by setting up a REST interface.

The way I am doing now is to pass to the EJS render function the template and a big JSON with the data to display:

```
res.render('template.ejs', jsondata); // jsondata is a big JSON object
```

In the template page I have the following two lines of code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var dataStr = '<%- JSON.stringify(jsondata) %>';
  var data = JSON.parse(dataStr);
  // ...other javascript code to perform super cool stuff on my page...
</script>
```

The problem is that I would like to reduce the amount of data to be passed to the client which might not be useful and allow the client to request the additional data it wants using jQuery Ajax get(). 
Therefor on the server side I would like to have also a RESTful api which will work alongside the one rendering EJS template pages (and possibly become the only one).

I fail to send JSON data not using the template engine. I would be a happier programmer if I could simply run from my server a function like this without errors

```
app.get('/rest/*', function(req, res) {
  // Some code which produces a result
  var result = { foo : 'bar'};
  res.json(result);
});
```

The problem seems to be that the template engine does not like to be by-passed and try to send JSON directly to the client.

What am I missing?

**EDIT**

Apparently it was a problem due to some silly mistake which I could not even reproduce. So, apparently EJS engine does not interfere with the `res.json()` function.

Here is my code on the server side, which I hope will help anyone facing a similar problem:

```
app.get('/rest/*', function(req, res) {
    var query = req.query;
    var user = req.user;

    console.log('query:');
    console.log(query);
    console.log('user:');
    console.log(user);

    // Some code which produces a result
    var result = { foo : 'bar'};
    res.json(result);
});
```

On the client side I have the following jQuery function:

```
<button id="application" onClick="perform_query(this.id)">This will make a query using a rest interface</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function perform_query(clicked_id) {
    var query = {};
    var queryEncoded = '';
    // Build the query
    query = {
      application : clicked_id,
      other: 'any other parameter'
    };

    // Encode the query
    queryEncoded = $.param(query);
    console.log(queryEncoded);

    var url = 'http://localhost:8080/rest/?' + queryEncoded;
    $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
      console.log( "success: " );
      console.log(data);
    })
    .done(function() {
      console.log('In done()');
    })
    .fail(function() {
      console.log('In fail() : Something went wrong!');
    })
    .always(function() {
      console.log('complete');
    });
  }
</script>
```

I hope I am on the right path... :)

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: REMOVE EXTENSION .ejs  like this   ... res.render('template', jsondata);